# iPhone - what is the difference between NSWeekCalendarUnit and NSWeekdayCalendarUnit?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to set a repeatingInterval of a UILocalNotification using these values but, as always, Apple docs are vague as hell.

Any clues?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe look at [this blog I just found](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/9/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html) about the subject?

AFAIK, `NSCalendarUnits` are primarely used to split a date or timeInterval into date components (`NSDateComponents`), to extract the weekday of a date, the year of the date, the hour component of a time, and so on.

In this context:

- the `NSWeekCalendarUnit` of a date correspond to the week index in the year (from 1st to 52nd week - or 53rd for years with 53 weeks)
- `NSWeekdayCalendarUnit` corresponds to the day in the week (from Mon to Sun)
- `NSDayCalendarUnit` corresponds to the day in the year (from 1 to 365)

When using the NSCalendarUnit type with `repeatingInterval`, the UILocalNotification will be triggered when the corresponding unit changes:

- `NSWeekCalendarUnit` will trigger the notification every week (every 7 days)
- `NSWeekdayCalendarUnit` will trigger the notification "every weekday", which corresponds to the same thing here as `NSDayCalendarUnit` which corresponds to "every day" in the context of a repeatingInterval.

Comment: Man, I have to take more vitamins, because my brain is hurting with this explanation. What you are saying is that when using in the repeatingInterval context: NSWeekCalendarUnit is ring the bell once a week at the same day of week and NSWeekdayCalendarUnit = NSDayCalendarUnit = ring the bell every single day, right? If this is true, someone at Apple is crazy and should be put in a straight-jaked inside a padded cell. For God's sake. Please confirm that. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes I confirm that, and that's logical. `NSWeekCalendarUnit` = once a week. `NSDayCalendarUnit` = once a day. `NSWeekdayCalendarUnit` = don't use it in the `repeatingInterval` context to avoid having headaches when reading your code again, and keep it for when you use it in the context of splitting a date into `NSDateComponents`.

Comment: why apple docs are not written like that? There are clearly two Apples:one amazing, simple, for the customer, one purgatory for developers. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually they are. Never forget to check out the Programming Guides which are really great resources people often forget about; Apple's doc is one of the most detailed I've ever seen and in a variety of topics, including Sample Codes, Programming Guides, the DevPedia, and so on, but most people only read the "Class References" (which is far from sufficient if you need more info on a given subject). In your situation, do go and read the [Dates and Times Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html)!!

Answer (score 2):

Cocoa and Objective-C make it easy to knock up quick test programs to see results. If you aren't sure of the documentation you can always check for yourself. I've got a project that builds a Foundation Command Line tool, and I just type these snippets into the main.m and log them just to see what the API returns.

For example, I just ran this:

```
unsigned flags = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"Week: %ld", [components week]);

flags = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"WeekDay: %ld", [components weekday]);
```

And got

```
Week: 37
Weekday: 7
```

It's quick to see that WeekCalendar unit gives this as the 37th week of the year and WeekDay says this (it's Saturday today) is the 7th day of the week ('cos I know that the Gregorian calendar counts Sunday as day 1).

Comment: thanks, but what do that mean in the context of UILocalNotification's repeatingInterval? that the notification will fire again every time 37 weeks or 7 days passed since the last time it fired?

Answer (score 0):

NSWeekdayCalendarUnit means every sunday ur notification will comming.

NSWeekCalendarUnit means every 7th day your notification will coming

Comment: isn't both the same? From one sunday to the next we have 7 days... my brain is hurting.

Comment: if u r add notification for current day and it is sunday in this case both are work same but if u want to add notification for only weeknd then u use NSWeekdayCalenderUnit. it means every weeknd u will getting notifiction. in nsWeekCalenderUnit meand current day to after 7 th day. your notification will commming.