# Scheduled Local Notifications Issue - Firing on a daily basis issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification

I've set up multiple Local Notifications on my AppDelegate for my universal app, 14 to be exact.  These notifications have specific times and weekdays when they should fire.

The problem is that **all of these notifications fire on a daily basis**.

For example, I have a notification set for Saturday morning, but it has been showing up daily.

Please give me a suggestion or direction as to why my notifications are firing daily?  I can't seem to find a solution.

Please check out my code, thanks!

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
/*
 Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
 If your application supports background execution, called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
 */


NSCalendar *gregCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [gregCalendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];


[dateComponent setWeekday:2];
[dateComponent setHour:11];
[dateComponent setMinute:44];



UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification setAlertBody:@"GOOD MORNING!"];
[notification setFireDate:[gregCalendar dateFromComponents:dateComponent]];
notification.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
[notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];


NSCalendar *gregCalendar1 = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponent1 = [gregCalendar1 components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];


[dateComponent1 setWeekday:3];
[dateComponent1 setHour:11];
[dateComponent1 setMinute:44];




UILocalNotification *notification1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification1 setAlertBody:@"GOOD MORNING!"];
[notification1 setFireDate:[gregCalendar1 dateFromComponents:dateComponent1]];
notification1.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
[notification1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification1];



NSCalendar *gregCalendar2 = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponent2 = [gregCalendar2 components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];


[dateComponent2 setWeekday:4];
[dateComponent2 setHour:11];
[dateComponent2 setMinute:44];



UILocalNotification *notification2 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification2 setAlertBody:@"GOOD MORNING!"];
[notification2 setFireDate:[gregCalendar2 dateFromComponents:dateComponent2]];
notification2.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
[notification2 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification2];

NSCalendar *gregCalendar3 = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponent3 = [gregCalendar3 components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];


[dateComponent3 setWeekday:5];
[dateComponent3 setHour:11];
[dateComponent3 setMinute:44];




UILocalNotification *notification3 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification3 setAlertBody:@"GOOD MORNING!"];
[notification3 setFireDate:[gregCalendar3 dateFromComponents:dateComponent3]];
notification3.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
[notification3 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification3];

NSCalendar *gregCalendar4 = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponent4 = [gregCalendar4 components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];


[dateComponent4 setWeekday:6];
[dateComponent4 setHour:11];
[dateComponent4 setMinute:44];




UILocalNotification *notification4 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification4 setAlertBody:@"GOOD MORNING!"];
[notification4 setFireDate:[gregCalendar4 dateFromComponents:dateComponent4]];
notification4.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
[notification4 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification4];





NSCalendar *gregCalendar5 = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponent5 = [gregCalendar5 components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];


[dateComponent5 setWeekday:2];
[dateComponent5 setHour:14];
[dateComponent5 setMinute:59];




UILocalNotification *notification5 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification5 setAlertBody:@"GOOD AFTERNOON!"];
[notification5 setFireDate:[gregCalendar5 dateFromComponents:dateComponent5]];
notification5.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
[notification5 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification5];

NSCalendar *gregCalendar6 = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponent6 = [gregCalendar6 components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];


[dateComponent6 setWeekday:3];
[dateComponent6 setHour:14];
[dateComponent6 setMinute:59];



UILocalNotification *notification6 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification6 setAlertBody:@"GOOD AFTERNOON!"];
[notification6 setFireDate:[gregCalendar6 dateFromComponents:dateComponent6]];
notification6.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
[notification6 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification6];


NSCalendar *gregCalendar7 = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponent7 = [gregCalendar7 components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];


[dateComponent7 setWeekday:4];
[dateComponent7 setHour:14];
[dateComponent7 setMinute:59];




UILocalNotification *notification7 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification7 setAlertBody:@"GOOD AFTERNOON!"];
[notification7 setFireDate:[gregCalendar7 dateFromComponents:dateComponent7]];
notification7.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
[notification7 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification7];

NSCalendar *gregCalendar8 = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponent8 = [gregCalendar8 components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];


[dateComponent8 setWeekday:5];
[dateComponent8 setHour:14];
[dateComponent8 setMinute:59];




UILocalNotification *notification8 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification8 setAlertBody:@"GOOD AFTERNOON!"];
[notification8 setFireDate:[gregCalendar8 dateFromComponents:dateComponent8]];
notification8.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
[notification8 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification8];

NSCalendar *gregCalendar9 = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponent9 = [gregCalendar9 components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];


[dateComponent9 setWeekday:6];
[dateComponent9 setHour:14];
[dateComponent9 setMinute:59];




UILocalNotification *notification9 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification9 setAlertBody:@"GOOD AFTERNOON!"];
[notification9 setFireDate:[gregCalendar9 dateFromComponents:dateComponent9]];
notification9.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
[notification9 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification9];

NSCalendar *gregCalendar10 = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponent10 = [gregCalendar10 components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];


[dateComponent10 setWeekday:6];
[dateComponent10 setHour:19];
[dateComponent10 setMinute:59];



UILocalNotification *notification10 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification10 setAlertBody:@"FRIDAY NIGHT!"];
[notification10 setFireDate:[gregCalendar10 dateFromComponents:dateComponent10]];
notification10.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
[notification10 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification10];

NSCalendar *gregCalendar11 = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponent11 = [gregCalendar11 components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];


[dateComponent11 setWeekday:7];
[dateComponent11 setHour:9];
[dateComponent11 setMinute:59];




UILocalNotification *notification11 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification11 setAlertBody:@"HAVE A GREAT WEEKEND!"];
[notification11 setFireDate:[gregCalendar11 dateFromComponents:dateComponent11]];
notification11.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
[notification11 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification11];

NSCalendar *gregCalendar12 = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponent12 = [gregCalendar12 components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];


[dateComponent12 setWeekday:7];
[dateComponent12 setHour:14];
[dateComponent12 setMinute:58];




UILocalNotification *notification12 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification12 setAlertBody:@"ENJOY YOUR WEEKEND!"];
[notification12 setFireDate:[gregCalendar12 dateFromComponents:dateComponent12]];
notification12.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
[notification12 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification12];

NSCalendar *gregCalendar13 = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponent13 = [gregCalendar13 components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];


[dateComponent13 setWeekday:7];
[dateComponent13 setHour:19];
[dateComponent13 setMinute:58];




UILocalNotification *notification13 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification13 setAlertBody:@"SATURDAY NIGHT PARTY!"];
[notification13 setFireDate:[gregCalendar13 dateFromComponents:dateComponent13]];
notification13.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
[notification13 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification13];



}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have to use NSWeekCalendarUnit, not NSWeekdayCalendarUnit for the repeat interval, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454465/iphone-what-is-the-difference-between-nsweekcalendarunit-and-nsweekdaycalendar.

Comment: Thanks Martin, so I should set it to: `notification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;` for each notification, but how would I declare it in my `NSDateComponents`? Is that necessary? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fire notifications at a specific day of the week at a specific time, the following code should work:

```
NSCalendar *gregCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [gregCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit  | NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

[dateComponent setWeekday:2]; // For Monday
[dateComponent setHour:11];
[dateComponent setMinute:44];

NSDate *fireDate = [gregCalendar dateFromComponents:dateComponent];

UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification setAlertBody:@"GOOD MORNING!"];
[notification setFireDate:fireDate];
notification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
[notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

The first part computes a date that is either on the next or on the previous monday.
The second part defines the notification with a repeat interval of one week.

It does not matter if the fire date is the previous monday, the "next fire date" will automatically adjusted to the next week. (You can verify that with `NSLog(@"%@", notification)`.)

Comment: Hi Martin, I implemented these changes to the code, but I am still having the same issues.  For example, the app just fired Notifications that are scheduled for Friday and Saturday. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you cancel all old notifications (`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]`) before scheduling the new set?

Comment: Thank you Martin. Ran some trials and the notifications are firing as scheduled!

Answer (score 1):

These lines are causing the notifications to repeat on a daily interval:

```
notification.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
```

remove those lines and it should fix your problem. The [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) say exactly what this property does:

> If you assign an calendar unit such as weekly (NSWeekCalendarUnit) or yearly (NSYearCalendarUnit), the system reschedules the notification for delivery at the specified interval. The default value is 0, which means don't repeat.

Comment: thank you for your response. I tried removing the `notification.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;` line of code before and it was still firing the Notifications on a daily basis. I'm kinda confused about the second part of the explanation though, should I still use the **repeatInterval**, but with the **NSWeekCalendarUnit** instead?  Thanks for your help!