# Local Notification Repeat Every Weekend Day

Tags: ios, ios8, uilocalnotification, nscalendar

My application uses local notifications to alert the user to wake up at a specific time. The are allowed to select repeat intervals so that the alert will repeat everyday, every weekday, and every weekend day.

I'm able to get the alert to repeat everyday, and weekday, but I'm having difficulty having the alert repeat on every weekend day.

So far I'm using `NSWeekdayCalendarUnit`  and `NSDayCalendarUnit` but there inst a calendar unit for weekend day. If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it!

Comment: This post might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454465/iphone-what-is-the-difference-between-nsweekcalendarunit-and-nsweekdaycalendar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "weekend" unit, and there is no way to specify a custom repeat. You will need to create two notifications and schedule one for every Saturday, the other for every Sunday.

Comment: I can't have one notification be assigned to both days?

Comment: Not directly, but the system copies notifications when you schedule them so you can reuse the same one and just change the start date.